Creating query for count of rows in a 24 hour window with window_start_dates
I have a table of rows in bigquery that has a userid and timestamp field createddate. I want the query to output userid, window_start_date, count(*) grouped by userid, window_start_date. The window_start_date is supposed to be the first row in the 24 hour window that starts at the first row after the previous 24 hour window ended. I wish I could base all the window_start dates on the days from the first row for each user but, a row can appear at any time and there could be gaps. For example, for one user, the original data would look like:



createddate




2024-07-15 10:50:00


2024-07-15 13:50:00


2024-07-16 11:50:00


2024-07-16 19:50:00


2024-07-19 12:50:00



The output of the query should be



window_start_date
cnt




2024-07-15 10:50:00
2


2024-07-16 11:50:00
2


2024-07-19 12:50:00
1



I currently am using the following query but know that it's flawed: the 24 hour window could be extended if a 24 hour gap isn't formed between rows. I want to make it so that at 24 hours and 1 second from the previous window start date, the next row is assigned as the window_start_date.
WITH
  original AS (
  SELECT
    userid,
    createddate
  FROM
    original_data 
  ),
 RollingWindows AS (
  SELECT
    userid, createddate,
    LAG(createddate) OVER (partition by userid ORDER BY createddate) AS prev_createddate
  FROM
    original 
),
window_starts AS (
  SELECT
    userid, createddate AS window_start
  FROM
    RollingWindows
  WHERE
    TIMESTAMP_DIFF(createddate, prev_createddate, SECOND) > 24 * 60 * 60
    OR prev_createddate IS NULL
),
joined_window_starts as (
select original .userid, createddate, max(window_start) window_start
from original 
join window_starts w on (
  def.userid = w.userid
)
where window_start <= createddate
group by 1,2
)
select userid, window_start, count(*) cnt
from joined_window_starts
group by 1,2
order by cnt desc


You need to create a session_id for it.
A typical way for it is to create an integer flag with condition to see the start of the new session. Then, do cumulative sum over these flags.
WITH
  original AS (
  SELECT
    userid,
    createddate
  FROM
    original_data 
  ),

session_flags AS (
  SELECT
  userid,
  createddate,
  TIMESTAMP_DIFF(createddate, LAG(createddate) OVER(PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY createddate), HOUR) >= 24 AS new_session_flag
  FROM tbl
),

sessions AS (
  SELECT
    userid,
    createddate,
    SUM(CAST(COALESCE(new_session_flag, FALSE) AS INTEGER)) OVER(PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY createddate) AS session_id
  FROM session_flags
)

SELECT
  userid,
  session_id,
  MIN(createddate) AS window_start,
  COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM sessions
GROUP BY userid, session_id

